# Switching from makeindex to xindy removes the index from TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, xindy, makeindex

I need `xindy` for Russian sort order in the index, but once I replace `makeindex` package with `xindy` the TOC entry for the index disappears.

How can I restore the index TOC entry?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
abc\index{abc}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

How to reproduce:

1. Compile with `pdflatex`
2. Run `texindy`
3. Compile again
4. Compile again as I used to when using `makeindex` and it would give me the TOC entry, but not with `xindy`

Comment: Recommended information: https://tools.ietf.org/doc/texlive-doc/latex/glossaries/glossariesbegin.html. Did you do it like `\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}`?

Comment: Adding a MWE would make things easier.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner MWE added. I was not aware that `xindy` could be used in more than one fashion.

Comment: Just before `\printindex`, add `\clearpage` and an `\addcontents` line (how to do the latter is covered in other questions here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using MakeIndex or Xindy doesn't make a difference here.

Pass the option `intoc` to `\makeindex`.

```latex
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}

\makeindex[intoc]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\chapter{First}
abc\index{abc}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

I suggest `\tableofcontents*` so that the TOC doesn't list itself.

[image]

Comment: This works, but for fairness sake, vanilla `makeindex` included itself in the TOC w/o that option.

Comment: @SuperAl It's `memoir`'s version of `theindex` that does, but `imakeidx` overrides it.